# Bounded call of call function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I am curious how bounded call function works inside in Javascript. The confusing example:

```
Number.call.bind(Array)(undefined, 1, 2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Indeed, instead of Number I can write any function and that will be ignored. My assumption is at some moment Array is called as a constructor function and 1 and 2 are passing as parameters. My question is what inside of call function leads to such a strange behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` is not much different from any other function (expect it can set `this` somehow). Here is a pseudo-code pseudo-version of `call`:

```
function call(thisArg, ...args) {
    let boundThis = this.bind(thisArg);
    return boundThis(...args);
}
```

So, all it really does is setting `this` of the function to the fist argument passed and then passes the remaining arguments to the function.

`call.bind(Array)` binds `this` inside `call` to `Array`, i.e. it "fixes" the function to which `.call` is applied to `Array`, meaning it will now always call `Array`. So you essentially have

```
let boundThis = Array.bind(thisArg);
return boundThis(...args);
```

which is basically `Array(...args)`.

Comment: Worth noting that this still suffers from the `Array(someNumber)` problem.

Comment: Probably shouldn't answer an ECMAScript 5 question with ES2015 features.

Comment: @Amit: Can't you see that this is pseudo-code and not ES6? :P

Comment: Yeah... you could say that, but you could also stick to "older standards" -it's your answer and you make the call. (Good answer anyway :-)

Comment: @Amit: Well, I could only express this with `.apply` in ES5 which probably doesn't make the whole thing easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter in [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is the "thisArg" with which the ***bound function*** is called. Since the bound function in your example is [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), that effectively returns a bound version of `call()` such that it is equivalent to `Array.call()`. The first argument for `call()` is the "thisArg" (yet again) with which the ***called function*** is called, and the rest are the parameters passed into the function. So now we're at `Array(1, 2)`, and that returns your output.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing, via bind, is no different from:

```
Number.call.call(Array, undefined,1, 2);
```

The above sends four parameters to the `call` on the right, the first of which is the context to call the `call` on the left. Thus, after the call on the right finishes, the code factors to:

```
Array.call(undefined,1, 2);
```

Which factors to:

```
Array(1, 2);
```

Notice that `Array` is actually the function being called.
It could be any other function rather than a constructor:

```
Number.call.call(alert, window,"hello world");
```